# Why is ActiveMQ about 20% faster with the memoryPersistenceAdapter?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using Active MQ with 99% non persistent topics. For some tests, where I used solely non persistent messages, I tried if forcing the broker to use the memoryPersistenceAdapter makes a difference. I changed the config to:

```
<beans>
    ... 
    <broker ... persistent="false"*>
    ... 
</beans>
```

It actually does make a difference! About 20% more throughput.

In theory, because nothing has to be persisted, there should not be any difference at all. What is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

Queue and topic persistence requires that the messages are written somewhere so that, upon provider/server restart, any undelivered messages are still present and available to be picked up.

Topic persistence is really only relevant when persistent subscriptions are in play, if there are no persistent subscriptions and no active consumers of the topic, the messages are immediately dropped anyway.

It is possible with a really large number of active messages and minimal number of consumer threads that processing could get behind so a provider/server restart would get the messages back...but then your consumer would have to connect almost immediately, I believe.